# Adding indexed non-stored fields to schema

Tags: solr, lucene

I added a new field in my schema that is indexed but not stored, so that I can copy another field into it. Do I still have to re-index all the documents because of this schema change? Or can I just restart my solr server? I looks like I have to re-index all documents since sorting on that new non-stored field is giving me unexpected results, but I would like a confirmation on that.

Comment: Alternately you could read the index using IndexReader and loop through the docs and make the necessary changes and write to a new index. This might save you some time if your index is huge and the bottleneck is the source data access/parsing etc.. You might need to Lucene Jars for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You have to full re-index. As schema change can  contain different  IndexAnalyzers Solr can't apply schema changes by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to run indexer to actually fill in the data to that filed